# Clang Linker escape $ for weak symbol

Tags: objective-c, makefile, linker, clang, gnu-make

I'm using Theos for a tweak but I'm having trouble with Makefiles and linker flags.

The Linker is complaining about an undefined symbol I'm so trying to pass `-Wl,-U, _OBJC_CLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass` for a weakly linked symbol like this,

```
ARCHS = arm64

TARGET := iphone:clang:latest:7.0
INSTALL_TARGET_PROCESSES = HookTest

include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = HookTestTweak

HookTestTweak_FILES = Tweak.m
HookTestTweak_CFLAGS = -fobjc-arc
HookTestTweak_LDFLAGS += -v -Wl,-U,_OBJC_CLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

At first, I thought it was the $, so I tried to escape it.

```
HookTestTweak_LDFLAGS += -v -Wl,-U,_OBJC_CLASS_$$_Hook_HTTestClass
```

But the linker just results in this (notice how it says `-U _OBJC_CLASS_`),

```
"/home/haow6/.theos/toolchain/linux/iphone/bin/ld" -dynamic -dylib -arch arm64 -dylib_install_name /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/HookTestTweak.dylib -platform_version ios 7.0.0 14.4 -multiply_defined suppress -syslibroot /home/haow6/.theos/sdks/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -o /home/haow6/source/HookTest/HookTestTweak/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/HookTestTweak.dylib -L/home/haow6/.theos/lib -L/home/haow6/.theos/vendor/lib -lobjc -framework Foundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework CydiaSubstrate -lc++ -U _OBJC_CLASS_ /home/haow6/source/HookTest/HookTestTweak/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o -lc++ -lSystem -F/home/haow6/.theos/vendor/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTTestClass", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass in Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_HTTestClass", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass in Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Next, I tried to encase the symbol name in quotes, and its closer with `-U "_OBJC_CLASS_\$_Hook_HTTestClass"` but it still doesn't work,

```
"/home/haow6/.theos/toolchain/linux/iphone/bin/ld" -dynamic -dylib -arch arm64 -dylib_install_name /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/HookTestTweak.dylib -platform_version ios 7.0.0 14.4 -multiply_defined suppress -syslibroot /home/haow6/.theos/sdks/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -o /home/haow6/source/HookTest/HookTestTweak/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/HookTestTweak.dylib -L/home/haow6/.theos/lib -L/home/haow6/.theos/vendor/lib -lobjc -framework Foundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework CydiaSubstrate -lc++ -U "_OBJC_CLASS_\$_Hook_HTTestClass" /home/haow6/source/HookTest/HookTestTweak/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o -lc++ -lSystem -F/home/haow6/.theos/vendor/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTTestClass", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass in Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_HTTestClass", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass in Tweak.m.bd8afb95.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I could use `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` but it complains that it's deprecated.

I hope I'm on the correct track but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` character is special to *both* make *and* the shell, so you have to escape it twice, once for each.

For `make`, you double it via `$$` to escape it.  For the shell, you include it in single quotes.  So try:

```
HookTestTweak_LDFLAGS += -v '-Wl,-U,_OBJC_CLASS_$$_Hook_HTTestClass'
```

Comment: Same result in the example with the quotes, `-U "_OBJC_CLASS_\$_Hook_HTTestClass"`

Comment: oh dear god, I made a typo. the symbol is `_OBJC_CLASS_$_HTTestClass` not `_OBJC_CLASS_$_Hook_HTTestClass`. Fixing that and using your advice made everything work. Thanks!